# pgfplots: I do not know the key '/tikz/nodes near coords' error

Tags: pgfplots, texlive, nodes-near-coords

I'm trying to create a simple plot using `pgfplots`. I have a problem though that drives me crazy. I'm working on a debian installation and had installed the tex-live version from the repositories. The code below was giving me the following error

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/nodes near coords' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

I though that the package was outdated and since there was no way to update it otherwise i removed the repo version of tex-live and install the one from their website (version 2011). I'm still getting the same error message though. I have to mention that the same code compiles correctly in my windows installation. Any idea why this might happen?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{\footnotesize {header title} }
\cfoot{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\title{my title}
\author{me}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{[\arabic{enumi}]}
\fontsize{11}{12}
\selectfont

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  [
    ybar,
    bar width = 1cm,
    xmin=1, xmax=1,
    xticklabels={,,},
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    xlabel={OpenCL implementation},
    ylabel={time (sec)},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords
  ]   
    \addplot coordinates {(1, 24.0)}; \addlegendentry{Version 1}
    \addplot coordinates {(1, 14.5)}; \addlegendentry{Version 2}
    \addplot coordinates {(1, 10.0)}; \addlegendentry{Version 3}
    \addplot coordinates {(1,  9.6)}; \addlegendentry{Version 4}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Figure caption}
\label{fig:example_caption}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have an outdated version of PGFplots. Can you add `\listfiles` to your preamble and check near the end of the `.log` file for your version number?

Comment: You have a typo `\addledendentry` should be `\addlegendentry`.

Comment: I changes the typo but the problem is still there. I will also correct in the question.

as for the version I believe you mean the following if I got it correct.

    `(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryplotm
arks.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2008/01/09 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.1)
    (/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2007/03/09 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))`

Comment: @gkaran89: No, I meant the `pgfplots` package: For example, after adding `\listfiles` to my preamble and compiling, I get the line `pgfplots.sty 2012/12/29 v1.5.1 DEV (git show 1.5.1-111-gcd08597 )` near the end of the `.log` file.

Comment: looks like you're using packages from the repos. these are outdated- get texlive from [http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html)

Comment: @cmhughes as I write I downloaded the latest version from the texlive website.

@Jake I get this: `pgfplots.sty    2011/12/29 v1.5.1 (git show 1.5.1-4-g53e640f )`

Comment: OK, new information. Apparently the problem is with TexMaker. When I compile from terminal everything is fine. When I compile from inside texmaker I get those errors.

Comment: @gkaran89: Check in "Options / Configure TeXmaker" whether it's configured to run `pdflatex` from the wrong directory.

Comment: sounds like you've got two texlives installed and TeXmaker is pointing to the wrong one

Comment: I set the paths to be absolute in TexMaker's settings. Now everything is ok. Probably there are still somewhere remains from the previous installation.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the error message the version of the `pgfplots` library is outdated.  You should upgrade to the latest version.

---

Using the latest version, and correcting the typo in the last line:

```
\addplot coordinates {(1,  9.6)}; \addlegendentry{Version 4}
```

I get the plot shown below. There are probably other `pgfplots/tikz` libraries that need updating. If you are just starting out, it would be best to do a fresh install of TeXLive and go from there.

[image]

Comment: I changed the typo, but it is not the case. The problem is still there.